# Difference between libzmq and cppzmq , and between zmq.h and zmq.hpp?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, installation, zeromq

For installation of ZeroMQ on Linux-Ubuntu , one website

https://tuananh.org/2015/06/16/how-to-install-zeromq-on-ubuntu/

says to run following commands :

**sudo apt-get install libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake**

**sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev**

in which we are installing libzmq-dev seperately.
Whereas according to

http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software

"*Make sure that libtool, pkg-config, build-essential, autoconf, and automake are installed.*"
So we dont need to install libzmq-dev explicity.

So my question is what difference does it make? what is the use of libzmq? Is it different from libzmq-dev ? If I want to code in C++ , then do I need to install both libzmq and cppzmq ,as given in https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq .

And please tell which header file( zmq.h ,zmq.hpp and zhelpers.hpp ) comes from which library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`libzmq` contains the zmq library only (libzmq.so, libzmq.a).

`libzmq-dev` contains the library and also C header file (zmq.h). If you want to develop with zmq, you need to use this one instead of `libzmq`.

> "Make sure that libtool, pkg-config, build-essential, autoconf, and automake are installed." So we dont need to install libzmq-dev explicity.

These tools are needed if you want to build libzmq from source code. No need to do that if you install via `apt`.

`cppzmq` is C++ binding for zmq so you can use C++ stuffs to work with ZMQ  instead via C api that libzmq provide.

`zmq.h` from `libzmq-dev`, zmq.hpp and zhelpers.hpp from `cppzmq`.

Comment: Thank you. I have another query. In my ZeroMQ applications (written in C++), I havent used zmq.h anywhere .So , does it mean I didn't need to install libzmq-dev? and can we write C++ application in ZMQ without installing libzmq ?@hgminh

Comment: No, `cppzmq` only give you C++ interface, the underlying works are done in the library `libzmq.so/.a`. Also, [zmq.hpp](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp) does use `zmq.h`.

Comment: Okay Thankyou . @hgminh You said " These tools are needed if you want to build libzmq from source code. No need to do that if you install via apt. " .. You mean install what ? Please explain

Comment: The aim here is to install library file (`libzmq.so/.a`) and header file (`zmq.h`). You can do it via apt (a package manager) which just download these files from somewhere. Or you can get the source code of zmq and compile it yourself to get library file. If you are not familiar this way, just install via `apt`.